# install windows 7 on windows 8 tablet possible?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, tablet

Is it possible to install Windows 7 on a Windows 8 tablet with an x86 architecture processor?

We have a software program that we want to display on the tablet but it is quite heavy and it only works with Windows 7. I have googled many different shops but they all ask way too much for a Windows 7 tablet, so reinstalling a Windows 8 tablet would be great, if possible.

Comment: Nearly anything that runs on windows 7 SHOULD run on windows 8 - so possibly asking about that specific issue may work better. You can install windows 7 off USB, so as long as you have drivers, so it shouldn't be an issue. Windows tablets DO tend to be more expensive, so getting a cost effective one may be tricky

Comment: Thank you for your awnser, so you tell me that reinstalling a windows 8 tablet with windows 7 is possible if I can find the drivers?

Comment: I'd probably do a full backup first in case you needed to restore it. Still, it makes more sense to try to work out why your program is not working on the tablet than to do a full install

Comment: Thank you for you awnser, deu to driver problems and the complexity of the program it simply isn't possible to run it on windows 8.

Comment: The sole problem you will have is drivers. If you cannot find drivers then there will be devices on the tablet that won't work. If this is your touch sensor its lets of an issue if you can dock the tablet, of course Windows 7 has horrible touch support, when compared to even the Windows 8 desktop.  I suggest you purchase a used tablet with Windows 7 if you need a tablet your unliekly will be unable to find a new one that supports Windows 7.

Comment: which tablet do you use? The Surface Pro only supports the 64Bit Windows 8 for example.

Comment: Hello magicandre, that is what were trying to find out, what tablet to use. We finally contacted the manufacturer of various tablet to ask wether it was possible. The biggest problem is like journeyman said is finding the proper drivers. We now have 1 new tablet (Acer iconia) which should be able to run windows7. But they also said that the warranty will drop if we do, but thats a chance we will take since the alternatives are atleast 2 to 3 times more expensive.

Comment: I rolled back to the revision before the spam was added. Was a link to a website that promoted a fake program with a ton of ads.  [Abhisek Kunar](https://superuser.com/users/637570/abhishek-kumar) please don't add that link to any answer or question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have found a Windows 7 tablet which we can use until we have developed our new solution.

To wrap up this answer: YES it is possible to install Windows 7 on a Windows 8 tablet, but always check wether there is support for the right drivers (in our case there wasn't) and the architecture of your processor. If money isn't an issue you can alway buy a hybrid laptop or one with a removable screen.

Answer (score 2):

My answer would be **feasible**, but highly not recommended.
Yes, it is possible since your tablet has an x86 architecture (or amd64...), but these devices are not so frequent on the market. Tablets usually have an ARM architecture, and as mentioned by Journeyman, Windows (non RT)-based tablets will be expensive.

Anyway, the term tablet often refers to small and light devices mostly controlled by fingers. The size of the screen would not be a problem for Windows 7, but the lack of mouse and keyboard will be.
You may bybass the problem with USB keyboard and mouse if your tablet has USB ports... but it will transform your tablet to a ... netbook !

So I definitively suggest you to acquire a cheap ultraportable laptop/notebook rather than a tablet.

HP mini 110 (350$), Acer aspire one 722 (300$) , Asus X101 (200+ $) may better fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your awnser, I have researched these possibilities but it has to be a tablet, no keypad or mouse, the application is originally controlled bij touch and none of the featured of Windows 7 have to be used just that program. Because hybrid laptops are quite expense as are tablets with windows 7 I thought to work around it by installing a cheaper X86 windows 8 tablet with windows 7. I understand it is weard but since we are still developing a mobile version of the application there has to be a solution to show it on a tablet. Thank you all for your awnsers!

Answer (score 1):

I just got a Taichi 21 and upgraded Windows 8 to Windows 7 on the Laptop.  Almost everything works with a combination of the Windows 8 and 8.1 drivers drivers except for the automatic screen rotation (accelerometer or g-sensor).  There is no unsupported device in device manger so I am unsure why it doesn't work but, as it turns out Windows 8 and 8.1 drivers probably will work in Windows 7.

Windows 7 works a lot better with classic desktop apps and touch input as it lets you open the keyboard on text fields with a pop-up keyboard icon or the taskbar icon.  Windows 8 requires the use of the taskbar icon or if the taskbar is covered a swipe right-left, settings, keyboard, "touch keyboard and handwriting panel" to get an on-screen keyboard.  If you do not use metro apps Windows 7 has better tablet support (minus the g-sensor issue).  The screen can still be rotated by manually selecting the orientation in screen resolution control panel.

Comment: "upgraded Windows 8 to Windows 7" - yes, it's an upgrade, indeed. :o)

Answer (score 0):

If you want Windows 7 functionality, in a windows 8 tablet, try http://www.classicshell.net/ . It's true freeware (w/o ads), and will give you a choice of Windows 2000, Windows XP, or Windows 7 GUIs in Windows Vista, 7, and 8/8.1. It's truly a magic-bullet for the malignant GUI beast.

One note of caution though, to enjoy full functionality, you will need some way to right-click the menus... Either through some touch interface in windows 8 (yes, windows 8 is still running the show, but it doesn't "feel" like it), or through a small bluetooth mouse.

Comment: No _tap-and-hold_ out-of-the-box for right-clicks?

Answer (score 0):

If the tablet is powerful enough (lots of ram basically), you could keep the Windows 8 and run a virtual machine that has Windows 7.  Even if you went with the native approach you could try that first.

Unfortunately in both cases (vm or native) your issue will be the touchscreen drivers.  Windows 7 is less likely to have them, and the manufacturer less likely to support them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to install Windows 7 on tablets. A Lenovo staff member wrote [in their support forums](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Tablets/Install-Windows-7-on-the-Thinkpad-Tablet-10/td-p/2064754):

> **Re: Install Windows 7 on the Thinkpad Tablet 10?**
>   ‎04-16-2015 11:21 AM
>
> It is not possible. Win7 can't run in pure UEFI without CSM (Compatibility Support Module), and the tablets don't have any CSM. Besides this, even if you could somehow install Win7 (which is not possible), there would not be any Win7 drivers. It's a dead-end. If you are a Win7-only shop, then these tablets aren't for you.